# Symfony/Twig radio style formbuilder

Tags: php, symfony, twig, formbuilder

I need to style each of radio button using Symfony form builder.

This is my part of my `createFormBuilder`:

```
->add('categoryId', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:Category',
                'property' => 'name',
                'required' => false,
                'expanded' => true ))
```

And in my twig template:

```
{% for child in form.categoryId %}
    <div class="radio i-checks col-md-3">
        <label>{{ form_widget(child, {'attr': { 'class': '', 'value': '' } }) }} </label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I display name of category (now I get empty values)?

When I'm using `child.get('name')`, I get this error

> Method "get" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by editing,

contoller:

`->add('categoryId', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:Category',
                'property' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => false,
                'choices' => $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('MyBundle:Category')
                    ->findAll(),
                'required' => true,
            ))`

And in my twig gallery:

`<div class="row">
    {% for child in form.categoryId %}
        <div class="radio i-checks col-md-3">
            <label>{{ form_widget(child, {'attr': { 'class': 'required', 'value': child.vars.value  } }) }} {{ child.vars.label }}  </label>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>`

I hope it will help someone. greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
child.name
```

(And i could not post this answer without entering at least 30 characters)

Comment: I was tried it but I get error `Method "name" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in MyBundle::add.html.twig`